# Inject retrofit android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, dagger-2

**ApiModule.kt**

```
@Module
class ApiModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRetrofit(): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideUserApi(retrofit: Retrofit): HeroesApi {
        return retrofit.create(HeroesApi::class.java)
    }


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApiManager(): ApiManager {
        return ApiManager()
    }
}
```

**ApiManager.kt**

```
class ApiManager {

    @Inject
    lateinit var mRetrofit: Retrofit

    fun getAllHeroes(): MutableLiveData<Result<List<Hero>>> {
        val mHeroesApi = mRetrofit.create(HeroesApi::class.java)
        return NetworkHandler<List<Hero>>().makeCall(mHeroesApi.getAllHeroes())
    }
}
```

**HeroesApi.kt**

```
interface HeroesApi {

    @GET("/marvel")
    fun getAllHeroes(): Call<List<Hero>>

}
```

Error i am getting

```
Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property mRetrofit has not been initialized
        at com.hardik.repository.network.ApiManager.getAllHeroes(ApiManager.kt:17)
        at com.hardik.repository.Repository.getHeroesFromNetwork(Repository.kt:16)
        at com.hardik.androidtemplate.usecase.GetHeroesUseCase.execute(GetHeroesUseCase.kt:14)
        at com.hardik.androidtemplate.viewmodel.HeroListViewModel.<init>(HeroListViewModel.kt:9)
```

Let me know for more details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to inject `Retrofit` instance in your `ApiManager`. You already have `Provide` method for `HeroesApi` in your `ApiModule` so you can directly pass it. First change your **ApiManager** with:

```
class ApiManager(private val mHeroesApi: HeroesApi) {

    fun getAllHeroes(): MutableLiveData<Result<List<Hero>>> {
        return NetworkHandler<List<Hero>>().makeCall(mHeroesApi.getAllHeroes())
    }
}
```

Then change your **ApiModule**

```
@Module
class ApiModule {

   // Rest code same as it is already

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    // Since you already have Provide method which provides HerosApi,
    // Dagger will automatically inject this below.
    fun provideApiManager(herosApi: HerosApi): ApiManager {
        return ApiManager(herosApi)
    }
}
```

**OR**

You can simply change your `ApiManager` to have `HorseApi` injected into constructor and you won't need to have `Provide` method for `ApiManager` even. For this, change **ApiManager** with following:

```
// Notice the @Inject before constructor
class ApiManager @Inject constructor(private val mHeroesApi: HeroesApi) {

    fun getAllHeroes(): MutableLiveData<Result<List<Hero>>> {
        return NetworkHandler<List<Hero>>().makeCall(mHeroesApi.getAllHeroes())
    }
}
```

and then, you can remove `Provide` method for `ApiManager` from `ApiModule` because your `ApiManager` only needs `HerosApi` in constructor and you have defined `Provide` method which returns `HerosApi` so dagger already knows how to construct your `ApiManager`.

So your **ApiModule** will finally look like this:

```
@Module
class ApiModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRetrofit(): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideUserApi(retrofit: Retrofit): HeroesApi {
        return retrofit.create(HeroesApi::class.java)
    }
    // There's no need for providing ApiManager.
}
```

Comment: Agree with your answer (+1).But I want to inject retrofit as field injection (Not through constructor) then how can i do ?

Comment: Field injection is only for classes which you can't construct yourself, for example Activity. For other classes like your ApiManager which you can construct yourself, you should always use constructor injection only. If you still want to have field injection, then you need to create a component for ApiManager with a method like `fun inject(apiManager: ApiManager)` and then in the init bloc of `ApiManager`, you'll need to write `yourApiManagerComponent.inject(this)`. I don't think you would like to do all this for field injection which isn't recommended here :)